# Parse file for specific word in line

Tags: regex, bash, sed

In my directory there are several files with the pattern

```
simulation_y_t
```

for all files with this pattern I would need to check whether in the last line of the file the word `hgip` comesup or not ...the word might not be separated by spaces from the surrounding characters but if it comes up it will come up within the last 20 characters of the line...

the last line of the file might look something like this (if it shall be removed)

```
((((1560:0.0129775,(1565:0.00473242,1447:0.00473242):0.00824512):0.0133245,((((1421:0.00357462,(1496:0.00352733,1472:0.00352733):4.72931e-05):0.00597691,1505:0.00955153):0.0104055,((((1465:0.00716479,(1527:0.00380709,1556:0.00380709):0.0033577):0.000984333,(1555:0.00381533,((1423:0.00169525,1411:0.00169525):0.00168847,1587:0.00338372):0.00043161):0.00433379):0.00159571,((1546:0.000908968,1584:0.000908968):0.00775293,(1492:0.00374859,1489:0.00374859):0.00491332):0.00108293):0.00962105,1594:0.0193659):0.000591157):0.00510731,(1442:0.0198716,(1525:0.00416688,(1550:0.00378343,1544:0.00378343):0.000383449):0.0157047):0.00519277):0.00123765):0.000318786,(1538:0.00713072,1530:0.00713072):0.0194901):0.000325926,((1483:0.00663734,1484:0.00663734):0.00471454,(1518:0.00352348,(1433:0.000365709,1450:0.000365709):0.00315777):0.0078284):0.0155948):0.00081517,1561:0.0277619):0.00127735):0.00271069hgip: 77113
```

note that the numbers and way the brackets are coudl be diffferent in every of the files it is really about whether these 4 characters appear in a row in that line ... if that do the line shall be removed from the file

how would i be able to do that?

Comment: how about taking the last line of your file and grepping for hgip?
tail -n1 yourfile |grep hgip

Comment: Do you only want to count matches where it's in the last 20 characters, or if it is somewhere else in the line should it not count?  That is, if `hgip` is in, say, the first 20 characters would that not count as a match for you?

Answer (score 1):

This should be easy

```
sed '/hgip/d' YourFile
```

This will delete all lines where 'hgip' is inside

For checking only last line

```
sed '${/hgip/d}' YourFile
```

This will delete only last line if 'hgip' is inside it

Answer (score 1):

Use find to search for the files and then use the -exec option to delete the last line if it contains hgip

```
find . -type f -name '*simulation_y_t*' -exec sed -i '${/hgip/d}' {} \;
```